# MediatR command with response that is not Unit.Value throws error

Tags: c#, mediatr

I am trying to upload a file, and return a result that is not Unit.Value.  If I add a return type, I keep getting an error.  If there is a way to use Unit.Value and return my object, that would be great, but I'm trying to figure out how to return a result set.

Here is my code segment.

```
   namespace Application.Group
{
    public class ReconcileCampaign
    {
        public class ReconcileCommand : IRequest
        {
            public IFormFile uploadFile { get; set; }
        }

        public class ReconcileResults
        {
            public List<Customer> ReconciledCustomers { get; set; }
            public List<Customer> NonReconciledCustomers { get; set; }
        }

        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<ReconcileCommand, ReconcileResults>
        {
            private readonly CEDbContext _ceDbContext;

            public Handler(CEDbContext ceDbContext)
            {
                _ceDbContext = ceDbContext;
            }

            public async Task<ReconcileResults> Handle(ReconcileCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                if (request.uploadFile.Length == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("No file included");
                }

                ReconcileResults rr = new ReconcileResults()
                {
                    ReconciledCustomers = new List<Customer>(),
                    NonReconciledCustomers = new List<Customer>()
                };

                return rr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my error.

> The type 'Application.Group.ReconcileCampaign.ReconcileCommand' cannot
> be used as type parameter 'TRequest' in the generic type or method
> 'IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>'. There is no implicit reference
> conversion from 'Application.Group.ReconcileCampaign.ReconcileCommand'
> to
> 'MediatR.IRequest<Application.Group.ReconcileCampaign.ReconcileResults>'.

This doesn't really make sense why does this.  I've seen examples where the response is bool or string, but why not an object?

Comment: `public class ReconcileCommand : IRequest<ReconcileResults> { ... }`

Comment: @asawyer, awesome!  That fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool. When in doubt read the documentation. The answer was there as well. https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#request-types

Comment: lol, I thought I did, but must have missed it.  I appreciate it!